# Create a URLConnection that can pass username and password in JAAS Security

Tags: java, proxy, proxy-authentication

Hi I have something like the following that makes a URL Connection
 and retrieves the data.  The problem
 is that when I hit a page that
 requires authentication first I get
 the login page.  I'm unsure of how to
 pass a username and password in the
 URLConnection.  I'm hitting a site
 that is using JAAS authenticaiton.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

.....

URL location = new URL("www.sampleURL.com");
URLConnection yc = location.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
    yc.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
    data += inputLine + "\n";
in.close();
```

I tried something like this but it didn't seem to work...

```
URL url = new URL("www.myURL.com");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
String login = "username:password";
String encodedLogin = new BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer(login.getBytes());
connection.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic " + encodedLogin);
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of "Proxy-Authorization", try "Authorization".  The "Proxy-Authorization" header is used when authenticating against a proxy rather than the actual web server you are trying to access.